# Why is my fried chicken batter soggy underneath?

Tags: deep-frying, chicken-breast

I dipped the chicken breasts in buttermilk, then a mixture of flour and potato starch, before frying at 390F for 3 mins. The chicken breasts were sous vide beforehand so the deep-frying step was just to give it the crust.

However, I have noticed that the batter skin is always soggy underneath:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean how could there possibly be water left under the skin after you dipped it in liquid and fried it for 3 full minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowing the buttermilk to drip off completely? I would either decrease the mixture (a scant coating), as it appears to be too much for this method of frying, or use a pre-made coating which is a bit thinner.